# Word-usage: Lean vs Support

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, vocabulary

These 2 words have the same translation in my native language, and I don't get the difference in these contexts. For example, should I say:

> Amanda *leant* her elbows on her thighs, *leaning* her hands on her head.
>
> Amanda *supported* her elbows on her thighs, *supporting* her hands on her head.

(I want to say that she put her elbows on her thighs, and put her hands below her head)

-

> Some students don't *lean* their notebooks on their desk, and therefore they have a sloppy handwriting.
>
> Some students don't *support* their notebooks on their desk, and therefore they have a sloppy handwriting.

(I want to say that they don't put their notebooks on their desk, so they don't have a good handwriting)

Comment: In English, the two words are often effectively *opposites*. So *The ladder **leans** on / against the wall* can be described from the opposite perspective as *The wall **supports** the ladder.* Does that help you see the difference?

Answer (score 1):

I generally agree with LawrenceC's answer, but there is a bit more to say.

*Lean* is one of many verbs in English which can be used as transitive or intransitive. The intransitive use refers to the object which is tilted (as LawrenceC says):

> The ladder was leaning against the wall.

The transitive use is causitive:

> I leaned the ladder against the wall.

*Support* is different: it is only transitive; and it is the surface or object which provides the support which is the subject:

> The wall was supporting the ladder.

If you use it with a person as subject, this is still true: it is not a causitive.

So, while you can say

> I supported the ladder against the wall.

this doesn't mean that I simply placed the ladder there, but that I went on holding it, making sure it didn't fall (presumably, while somebody was climbing it). I wasn't just causing it to support, but actually supporting it.

Answer (score 0):

*X leans on Y* or *Z leans X on Y* specifically means *X tilts (or is made to tilt by Z) toward Y far enough to touch it*.  This usually means either X or Y is supported by the other.

If you replace the above with *support*, tilting *might* be involved but other methods of keeping X on Y could be used.

> I leaned the board on the table (Board is tilted).
>
> I supported the board on the table (Board might actually be on top of the table somehow with something else involved, like a small box, etc. - or you might be physically holding it there)

Now, for this:

> Some students don't lean their notebooks on their desk, and therefore they have a sloppy handwriting.

*Lean* is generally a "vertical" thing.  If the student's desks aren't very vertical (anything called a "desk" probably isn't), *lean* is the wrong word.  You want to say *lay flat on*.

> > Some students don't lay their notebooks flat on their desk, and therefore they have a sloppy handwriting.